# Selection Sort C++ Wrong Output for one element?

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

For the following implementation of **Insertion Sort** when i used random function to generate an arbitrary input,  it gave wrong output since one element appears wrongly placed as **Highlighted** in Picture. I tried hard to understand whereas is the mistake, but couldn't figure it out. What is **Wrong** in my Code ?

[image]

```C++
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template <class Item>
void exch(Item &A, Item &B)
{
    Item t = A ; 
    A = B; 
    B = t; 
}

template<class Item>
void selection(Item list[],int last)
{
    Item holdData;
    int smallest,current,walker;

    for(current=0;current<=last;current++)
    {
        smallest = current;
        for(walker=current+1;walker<=last;walker++)
        {
            if(list[walker] < list[smallest])
                smallest = walker;

            //smallest selected, exhange with the current
            exch(list[smallest],list[current]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 20;
    int *a = new int[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) a[i] = 1000*(1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);

    cout<<"Before sorting : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    selection(a,N-1);

    cout<<"\n\nAfter Sorting : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Should this: `for(current=0;current<last;current++)` be `for(current=0;current<=last;current++)`?

Comment: @Galik Still gives wrong output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
smallest = current;
for(walker=current+1;walker<=last;walker++)
{
    if(list[walker] < list[smallest])
        smallest = walker;

    //smallest selected, exhange with the current
    exch(list[smallest],list[current]);
}
```

Here `smallest` isn't actually selected yet, put it outside the loop:

```
smallest = current;
for(walker=current+1;walker<=last;walker++)
{
    if(list[walker] < list[smallest])
        smallest = walker;
}
//smallest selected, exhange with the current
exch(list[smallest],list[current]);
```